# Does it make sense to replace nan values by -99999?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

how does it make sense to replace `nan` values in the dataframe by the value `-99999`? I found it here, example 3: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-replace/

`df.replace(to_replace = np.nan, value =-99999)`

Maybe `-99999` should simply represent `-infinite`, but which intention could be behind this operation? Any ideas, guesses? :/

I'd appreciate any advise!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing missing values with `0`. Like @Bruno mentioned most `machine learning algorithms` do not work with missing values in your dataset.

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: 0 works too! But it really depends on the situation if the value can be 0 in the column maybe it is better to avoid it, the same applies to -99999. The main idea is to just avoid a real value

Comment: True, if 0 exist in the variable, then 0 might not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Some machine learning models don't run with NaN values in the input such as RandomForest in scikit learn, so it makes sense to replace it by another value so you can run the model without losing the information that this value is a NaN, you can choose any value you want by values that differ largely from other such as -99999 are better to represent this information